# Lua Plugins Containing Local Variables

Tags: plugins, lua, global-variables, local-variables

I'm trying to learn the Lua language to develop plugins for my company's products.  To help me learn (along with PiL book, Reference Manual, and numerous online resources), as I read I try to decipher current plugins we use.

One thing I've noticed is that `local` variables are listed at the very top and are not set to a specific value.  For example: `local SendVar` and `local EndVar`.

But later on, many `function`'s and `local` var's are used.

My question: I understand "Scope", `global` and `local` variables.  But if there are no `local function`'s within the plugin, are *all* `local` variables used within all `functions`?

I'm sorry for any confusion.  But I'm trying to figure out how plugins are used within another program that uses other Lua plugins.  I'm taking a wild guess when stating that unless `local function`'s are otherwise stated, all `local` variables are used *within* that plugin file *only*.

Am I correct?

Comment: Your terminology is not clear, and also what you really want to know is not too clear. What do you mean by "plugin"? Do you mean "Lua script"? "Lua modules"? Anyway I try to build an answer below.

Comment: What do you mean by "But if there are no local functions within the plugin, are all local variables used within all functions"? Can you clarify this part?

Comment: I deeply apologize for not conveying my question clearly.  I knew my question was confusing when I was confusing myself.  The "plugin" is a Lua file that will be implemented via controller GUI.  Once loaded, the file will be located and utilized.  (I hope that helps to clarify your mind Lorenzo.  Toxic, there are no `local function`'s within the file.  Only `local` variables.  They can be found within different `function` chunks and outside of them.

Comment: BTW, why don't you post a significant fragment of the code you are referring to. This may ease our understanding of your doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in Lua you write a `local` statement, you are declaring that the following identifiers will denote local variables, whether or not those statements actually initializes the variables.

Moreover, local variables in Lua have **block scope**, i.e. they are visible in the block in which they are defined and in every enclosed block. Blocks are, for example, function bodies, `then-end` or `else-end` blocks, `do-end` blocks, etc.

Keep in mind, also, that variables in Lua don't have type, their value have.

```
-- declares `a` as a local variable (having no value, i.e. `nil` value)
local a   
-- declares `b` as a local variable having 2 as value
local b = 2  
-- declares `f` as local var having a function as value
local f = function(x) return x * x end  

do
    -- `a`, `b` and `f` are visible here, because this is a block enclosed 
    -- in the block where those vars were declared

    local aa = 2

end

-- `aa` is not visible here, because it was declared in an inner block
```

Comment: Note that *the entire file* is also a "block", and thus locals declared at the top level of the file are local to the file as a whole.

Comment: @Lorenzo, thank you for your example code.  Now what happens if your example `local f = function(x) return x*x end` actually stated `local f = function(args) if args then values end local a = values end`?  That is actually what I was trying to explain.  @ToxicFrog, that is *exactly* what I meant (partially) but yes that's it in a nutshell.  Thank you!!!

Comment: @Lorenzo Donati, basically, even though `local a` is `nil` at the top, the example plugin file assigns `local a` a value through a `function` later. Why would a programmer give a list of `local`'s with a known `nil` value only to give it a value within a following `function` later? Why not just wait until you need it then give it a variable?  I think that is what is really tossing me for a loop right now.

Comment: @Pwrcdr87 So you're asking why not declare the local variable closer to its point of use? One reason might be that *that* variable needs to be visible from another function. Putting it closer to point of use might make that variable inaccessible in this case.

Comment: @ToxicFrog Yep, I was about to add that, but my internet connection is having glitches tonight. :-(

Comment: @Pwrcdr87 Declaring a local without giving it a value prevents that variable to be interpreted as a global var in the code that comes next. So you can do `local a`, then you are sure that, from that point on and in the same block, whenever you refer to `a` you are using that local `a` and not a global named `a`. As greatwolf pointed out, declaring a local so early could be needed to extend its scope across multiple function definitions (for example).

Comment: Again, I apologize for not being clear.  But I completely understand the reasoning for this now.  Thank you both so very much.